# AppEngine - ndb - Unindexed properties not working?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to understand how builtin indexes work in AppEngine. Documentation says that passing "indexed=False" to the constructor stops indexing the property but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I have the following code:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class IndexedClass(ndb.Model):
    prop1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
    prop2 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

class UnindexedClass(ndb.Model):
    prop1 = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    prop2 = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        for i in range(10):
            IndexedClass(
                prop1=i,
                prop2="Item %s" % i
            ).put()
            UnindexedClass(
                prop1=i,
                prop2="Item %s" % i
            ).put()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

If you execute it in GAEL and create statistics you get this: [image]

It reports the same builtin indexes for both indexed and unindexed classes.

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me out what I am doing wrong.

A similar app deployed on AppEngine has more unindexed properties in the model, and [image: here are the stats] declared like this:-

```
aProperty = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Geography', indexed=False)
```

As you can see we have over 2M entities using 947Mb. We have 40M indexes using 5Gb of data. These unwanted built-in indexes take up 5x more space than the entities themselves. Thus we are paying 5x more for storage, and 10x more for write ops than the documentation states.

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Comment: You're **not** showing us the indexes -- you clicked on "Datastore Viewer", **not** "Datastore Indexes".  Please fix that and edit your Q accordingly!

Comment: That's correct, my question is related with builtin indexes. The image shows the datastore automatically generated statistics. Please look at columns 4 & 5 of the attached image. Does it have to create builtin indexes for unindexed properties? This is very important when writing entities in BULK as Write Operations increase dramatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unindexed properties definitely make their job in practice: they will not be registered on index tables, thus you will not be able to use them in projection queries nor filters.

However, you are right about the stats. The picture you showed there got me really intrigued. Going into the guts of the SDK there is the class DatastoreStatsProcessor, which seems to be the one responsible to aggregate the results you see when you trigger [a stats update](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/admin/datastore_stats_handler.py#30). In the method [__AgreggateTotal](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stats_generator.py#473) it seems that it does not make any differentiation between indexed and unindexed properties: in the [__GetPropertyIndexStat](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stats_generator.py#139) method, it always return 2 for every property, which explains the results you are getting after generating stats.

It'd be worth checking what you see the [Google Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) once your project is deployed. Storage->Datastore->Dashboard. Shamefully enough I do not have any deployed project working with unindexed (or Blob or Text properties).
What about you?

Comment: Thanks Jose. I agree. Your first statement is correct. This is the behaviour I have. The problem is the builtin indexes generated for unindexed properties. I've posted a real example in the question showing the exact same problem. Any ideas? This is an extra cost that looks unnecessary to me.

Comment: Yeah exactly same issue I am also facing even for `TextProperty` also it's trying to index it because of which while storing long string I am getting `The value of property "{field_name}" is longer than 1048487 bytes.` which according to their documentation shouldn't happen.